# Devise: Using only SQL to change passwords

Tags: sql, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication, and I need a way to quickly change every user's password to be the same password so that I can test locally using production data. Because there are a bazillion callbacks in this legacy codebase, and innumerable surprises lurking, and because it takes a really long time for the Rails environment to load, I would like to be able to do this in one SQL query.

So, I created a user, set the user's password to "Passw0rd" in the UI, then grabbed that `encrypted_password` field and copied it to all the other users, but Devise busted me for having an invalid hash. I assume this means that the encrypted password is salted somehow using other pieces of the user entry, which is pretty smart, but it makes it hard to imagine how I'll accomplish this in SQL.

Does anyone know how the `encrypted_password` field is structured so that I could roll my own in the database?

Comment: If you can change a user's password with `user.password=...` then you can do that for every other user. Just do `User.update_all(:password => "password")`

Comment: I'm obviously aware that that's possible, but I wanted a way of doing it directly in SQL so that I can guarantee that no callbacks on users get called.

Comment: Well, what is your Devise version? A lot has changed in Devise in the past year. For example, the current version no longer needs a `password_salt` field in the database. What you need to do, is go to [Devise's releases page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/releases). Now, copy the commit reference of the version you are using. Then, use GitHub's search and find the location of `password=`. Now substitute the commit reference in the url. Now see what the `password=` method is doing.